# include based on route Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

How do I include a file based on which route "category" is used with blade with Laravel? I'm basically trying to do this in the sub nav part of my view template:

app/views/layouts/default.blade.php

```
@if (Route::resource() == 'tasks')
    @include('navs.task')
@elseif (Route::resource() == 'projs')
    @include('navs.proj')
@elseif (Route::resource() == 'miscs')
    @include('navs.misc')
@else 
    @include('navs.info')
@endif
```

but that throws the error "Undefined class constant 'resource' "

Answer (score 1):

Very late, but i think using Request::is is an easier way.

```
@if (Route::is('tasks'))
   @include('navs.task')
@elseif (Route::is('projs'))
   @include('nav.proj')
@elseif (Route::is('miscs'))
    @include('nav.misc')
@else 
    @include('nav.info')
@endif
```

Also this is alot of if else's use Switch case instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're after Route::currentRouteName().

```
@if (Route::currentRouteName() == 'tasks')
    @include('navs.task')
@elseif (Route::currentRouteName() == 'proj')
    @include('navs.proj')
@elseif (Route::currentRouteName() == 'misc')
    @include('navs.misc')
@else 
    @include('navs.info')
@endif
```

Answer (score -1):

Michael P: your answer led me to a correct answer.  Route::currentRouteName() returns 'task.index' or 'proj.create' which is too granular.  Route::current()->getUri() works.

```
@if (Route::current()->getUri() == 'tasks')
    @include('nav.task')
@elseif (Route::current()->getUri() == 'projs')
    @include('nav.proj')
@elseif (Route::current()->getUri() == 'miscs')
    @include('nav.misc')
@else 
    @include('nav.info')
@endif
```